# Is it safe to call getsockname() while a nonblocking stream socket is connecting?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, posix, nonblocking

If I create a stream socket, and I make it nonblocking, and I request it to connect to a remote host and the `connect()` call returns with `EINPROGRESS`, is it safe to issue a `getsockname()` call on it and to expect the returned local address to be correct?

Comment: 1st rule of programming: If something can go wrong it will go wrong!

Comment: No doubt, so I am summoning the shared wisdom of the community :)

Comment: No, it is not safe... you may choke on a pizza or break your finger typing the code! But the returning address will be correct, there's no reason for it to be not to.

Comment: @n.m. Yes there is. TCP may not yet have chosen the route for example, or allocated the local port. OP this isn't safe.

Comment: In any case you are supposed to check the value returned by `getsockname()`

Comment: @EJP `getsockname` would return an error in that case, not an incorrect address.

Comment: @EJP Or actually it will return a zero-filled address (still technically valid I guess).

Comment: @n.m. If it returns a zero-filled address it is useless for the OP's purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this question is tagged Linux: I looked up the sources (Kernel 3.4.103 [af_inet.c: inet_stream_connect](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/net/ipv4/af_inet.c?id=refs/tags/v3.4.103) and [tcp_ipv4.c: tcp_v4_connect](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c?id=refs/tags/v3.4.103)) and found that connecting to a non-blocking (IPv4) socket indeed is implemented the way that `EINPROGRESS` is returned by [`connect()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) **after** the setup of the local socket's address:port had been performed and **before** the connection's handshake had been established.

So (at least for Kernel 3.4.103) a call to [`getsocketname()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getsockname.2.html) should be safe.

However POSIX does not specify this behaviour ([as of Issue 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/connect.html)), so just do not rely on this.

Answer (score 3):

getsockname returns the address the socket is bound to. The first thing when starting with the connect is to bind the socket to a local address and port (unless it was already bound by the user). This is a local and non-blocking operation. Therefore you should get a usable value from getsockname even while the connection is still in progress.

For this argumentation I assume that you only call getsockname after the connect call returned with EINPROGRESS and not from another thread while connect did not return yet. The argumentation is also based on the fact, that there is no special behavior defined for the bind system call for non-blocking sockets. This suggests that the binding itself will not block. Also, the lookup in the routing table to determine the local address to be use for the connection should also be only using existing in-kernel data and thus not block.

Comment: Can't agree with that. If it's non-blocking, it may not have completed. It still takes a finite time. You would need some specification that says that the bind step is complete when connect() returns. If there is one, OK, otherwise not.

Comment: @EJP:  I'm sure connect will not return with EINPROGRESS before it bound the socket. If you call getsockname from another thread while connect did not return that would be another thing (edited answer to make this clear).

Comment: @EJP: and O_NONBLOCKING relates only to non-blocking I/O. There is no I/O on the socket involved in binding.